# What was the first operating system to feature a separate kernel?

Tags: history, operating-system

Kernels are programs that abstract the hardware of a computer to some extent, allowing other programs to use standardised system calls (e.g. `malloc`) to perform hardware tasks (e.g. writing to memory, displaying text on a screen) without resorting to "special memory values" or machine-dependent hacks.

Many early operating systems functioned as kernels. But by 1985 and the release of AmigaOS, separate kernels existed (i.e. Exec). When was the first independent* kernel** created?

<sup>* Where "independent" means "able to function without, or separately from, (the rest of) an operating system".</sup>
<sup>** Where "kernel", more specifically, means "resident monitor that is callable by user programs". ([Thanks Ken Gober](/posts/comments/2635)!)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your definition of "independent kernel". Do you mean something like "microkernel" (other parts of the OS are moved "outside")? Most kernels were more or less modularized, and had a scheduler and memory management routines somewhere that in principle could have worked on their own, it's just that the rest of the kernel was usually also present, because it was needed anyway and it wasn't seen as necessary to do a strict separation. Even, say, Linux today doesn't do this.

Comment: @dirkt Linux *does* do this; GNU can be taken off and replaced by, say, Android, and the kernel will still work. Although I appreciate that I haven't been clear; I'll try to reword it.

Comment: Well, for *every* OS you can take the programs (user and system) and replace them with different programs, if you bother to invest the additional effort to write them, while retaining the kernel. Nearly all OS had a layered design, and system programs and utilities. Maybe look at the wikipedia article for [microkernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel), it also mentions the *RC 4000* system as ancestor of microkernels. But on early hardware, microkernels were just too expensive.

Comment: I read the question as looking for the first operating system where one could identify separate runtime components within the operating system itself (where "operating system" is defined as the components providing the system calls — which incidentally doesn't include `malloc`). AmigaOS has Exec, Intuition, and AmigaDOS at least; Linux doesn't apply IMO because you can't run portions of the kernel separately (modules become part of the kernel when loaded).

Comment: I think that if you use the term "resident monitor" rather than "kernel" this question becomes easier to answer.  In particular, I think the question being asked here is "what is the first resident monitor that was callable by user programs?"

Comment: The question is really confusing, mixing "standardised system calls" with with library calls, where the latter provides a standard calling interface, but a kernel interface guarantees a better de-coupling of a kernel and a task running on such kernel. To be machine-independent (kind of hardware abstraction) is just a special aspect what kernels usually provide. The question might targeting OSes and kernels which are divided into a HW dependent and a HW independent parts for easier platform porting or to provide different system environments, like Apollo DomainOS driving BSD, SysV or Aegis.

Comment: @JohannKlasek Do you have any suggestions for how it could be improved?

Comment: First malloc is not a kernel call (at least on Linux). Not all CPUs have a protected (user) mode. So the first kernel based OSs came up simultaneously with the first CPUs having protected mode!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Reading through Per Brinch Hansen's [The evolution of operating systems](http://brinch-hansen.net/papers/2001b.pdf) paper, I get the impression the two main candidates for operating systems with identifiably separate kernels are

- Dijkstra's [THE multiprogramming system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THE_multiprogramming_system), started in 1965; it's a layered operating system — so you could view its layer 0 as a kernel, which is smaller than the whole operating system;
- Hansen's own [RC 4000 multiprogramming system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_4000_multiprogramming_system), built in 1969; it's the first operating system designed as separate components communicating with each other (which led to what are now known as [microkernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel)).

To answer the revised question about callable monitors, the same paper indicates that

> Atlas was the first system to exploit *supervisor calls* known as “extracodes”:
>
> > Extracode routines form simple extensions of the basic order code, and
> >     also provide specific entry to supervisor routines.

The [Atlas system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_%28computer%29) here is a computer built at Manchester University in the early 1960s.

Hansen's excellent book, [Classic Operating Systems](http://www.springer.com/book/9780387951133), reprints papers describing all these systems (and others) in detail. Regarding the Atlas supervisor:

> It becomes activated in several different ways. Firstly, it can be entered as a direct result of obeying an object
>   program. Thus, a problem being executed calls for the supervisor whenever
>   it requests an action that is subject to control by the supervisor, such as
>   a request for transfer to or from peripheral equipments or the initiation of
>   transfers between core store and magnetic drums; the supervisor is also activated when an object program requires monitoring for any reason such as
>   exponent or division overflow, or exceeding store or time allocation.

Comment: The Manchester Atlas came to my mind as well when I read the question. I think it was also pretty much the first computer with virtual memory.

Comment: Danish DASK used a microkernel like architecture long before anyone knew that microkernels was an option. I don't recall the exact year it was programmed, but it was during the time that memory was stored in drums.

Comment: @Clearer that’s intriguing — could you write a little more about it, perhaps in a separate answer?

Comment: @StephenKitt I'd prefer if I could find the book I read it in before adding any more details. I'm at work at the moment, but I'll look it up when I get home.

Comment: @Clearer of course! I wasn’t expecting anything quickly, I just wanted to indicate my interest.

Comment: @StephenKitt I seem to have misremembered a few details (no drums involved). The operating system I was refering to was used in Regnecentralen's RC4000, which was produced from 1969. Per Brinch Hansen was one of the designers of the system. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regnecentralen and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_4000_multiprogramming_system for more details. The interesting bit is the operating system, being, essentially, a miniature version of a microkernel. It has horrible performance though.

Comment: @Clearer that matches what I’d read; the DASK was too small for an operating system (but it did have drums for storage). Check out [Hansen’s memoirs](http://brinch-hansen.net/memoirs/contents.html), they’re an interesting read! And my answer already mentioned the RC 4000 ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt You did mention the RC 4000 :-) My apologies for not having paid enough attention.

Answer (score 8):

In the realm of microcomputers specifically, the BBC Micro of 1981 had [a very sophisticated kernel in ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acorn_MOS) for a machine of its class.  There were a number of defined entry points that both language ROMs and user programs were expected to use to interface with the hardware.

Programs which relied exclusively on these interfaces could expect to run correctly on future versions of the BBC Micro *and* on the 6502-based incarnations of the [Second Processor expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_(BBC_Micro)).  Much of this functionality was exposed in a programmer-friendly manner by the included version of BASIC.

For example, to draw text or graphics on the screen, you were expected to send ASCII characters, control codes and escape sequences to the VDU driver through the OSWRCH entry point at &FFEE - which was always present, even if the display memory had been remapped into the shadow bank (on the Master) or simply didn't exist in your memory space (on the Second Processor).  Most graphics operations could be specified through a six-byte escape sequence corresponding to the BASIC PLOT statement.  To check the colour of a pixel, or to perform a variety of auxiliary operations such as hiding the text cursor, the more general OSBYTE entry point could be used.

Some games found this interface too restrictive for adequate performance, so they had to access display memory directly.  These games were consequently incompatible with the Second Processor and Shadow RAM, but could still be run on a machine so equipped, by temporarily disabling those features.

Other [entry points](http://mdfs.net/Docs/Comp/BBC/API/) dealt with handling a very basic command shell, filesystem operations (abstracted so that you didn't need to care about tape/floppy/HDD/network differences), and so on.

This approach to constructing an operating system was considered so successful that it was copied very closely in the subsequent Acorn Archimedes series, which introduced the now-ubiquitous ARM CPU to the world.

The story goes that a more professional microkernel-based OS (ARX) was being developed for the Archimedes, but that it was so slow and memory-hungry that it would have ruined the machine for its intended market.  A large part of that was because it was written in Modula-2 via an incredibly inefficient compiler; to multiply two integers it would emit 25 ARM instructions and *then* call a subroutine.  (The ARM2 could already do that with a single instruction.)

A demo was arranged, where the ARX devs proudly showed off sixteen clocks running on their desktop - under which load their top-of-the-line 4MB machine was swapping heavily, and each clock only updated every several seconds.  The other team came in with a 256KB machine running the MOS-derived OS (Arthur), and they had sixteen clocks written in BBC BASIC, all running smoothly.  ARX was cancelled the next day, and Arthur eventually became RiscOS.

Yes, that means you can still [call OSWRCH and OSBYTE natively](https://www.riscosopen.org/forum/forums/12/topics/9481) on a Raspberry Pi!

Answer (score 3):

Even an OS kernel on a some very modern system (certainly compared to what is relevant here) uses "special memory values" and machine dependent hacks to provide an ABI.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64

"Independence" of a kernel could likely be best measured by whether the kernel can force user programs not to interfere with it or not. This became possible as soon as memory management units or comparable hardware became available commercially - and likely operating systems quickly followed since these features - that were expensive to build in pre-single-chip-CPU systems - would be useless without an OS taking advantage of them.
Architectures like IBM 370, DEC VAX and part of PDP-11 were tailored to such usage, and ran UNIX, VMS and even hypervisors in case of the 370 from the 1970s on. Home/Office grade computers only partially had that kind of feature set - the first widely used microprocessor CPUs that were capable without extra hardware were the 80286 (limited, the 80386 had far better features in that area) and Motorola 68030.

....

Added detail on why I said "limited" about the 80286: IIRC it was bugged and once you switched into protected/virtual memory mode (an x86 cpu always boots with these features switched off!), any attempt to return it to "real" mode (which you needed to do I/O) utterly crashed it unless you added extra hardware to guard against it (the A20 gate logic in the PC architecture).

Comment: On a 286, you need real mode to call the BIOS (unless you have an ABIOS), not to do I/O. You can write a protected-mode OS on a 286 without relying on external hardware, you just can’t use real-mode code inside it (so no BIOS except during initialisation before the PM switch, and no DOS which was the real killer at the time).

Comment: Didn't all 80286 PC's beginning with the IBM AT include the software reset ability to get the CPU back to real mode?

Comment: @BrianH Not sure about "ability". Going by Wikipedia, the documented way of doing it was via the keyboard controller, but it turned out that triple faulting the CPU was faster. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_fault#Other_uses

Comment: @Brian check out [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/219/79) for info on the 286 and tricks to reset it to real mode. The [LOADALL](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1006/79) question is also relevant.

Comment: Expanding on @StephenKitt's first comment above: the problem with the 80286 and switching to real mode wasn't a bug, but a lack of foresight from the design team. They simply never considered backwards compatibility; they assumed that once a processor was switched to protected mode that there'd be no reason to ever return to real mode, so didn't design in any way of doing so. Protected mode was so obviously better, that they assumed all software would be reimplemented to use it in short order and real mode would be a forgotten relic. This did of course happen, but not as quickly as they hoped.

Comment: Also the A20 gate wasn't really about protected mode at all, but was a backwards compatibility hack: 8086 programs were sometimes written to assume that memory above the 1MB limit wrapped back around to address zero, but with the larger address bus of the 80286 this didn't happen.  The A20 gate hardware mimicked the behaviour of the 8086 to prevent those programs crashing.